# Get the values in picker from server

Tags: iphone, web-services, titanium, picker

I want to get some values to the picker dynamically. Statically it is performing well. But when I want to add picker row dynamically from calling web service, there is an occurrence of NSRangeException. Whether the array having data and I am able to alert that data. I am using Titanium SDK for this iphone application.

```
if(gameTypeName.length>0){
    alert(gameType.length);
    picker.add(gameTypeName);   

}
```

The array is creating as:

```
var typeName = college[j].GameTypeName;
gameTypeName.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({title:typeName}));
```

Whether it is working fine with static data as:

```
var picker_data = [
Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Title 1',value:'1'}),
Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Title 2',value:'2'})
];

picker.add(picker_data);
```

Comment: If you can post whole code than i think i can give a try. At least post code of this picker filling part only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, the Picker doesn't have a "Value" property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pickerView. But, easy to use Table View. you set array data in you TableView (tableView.data =;). 
and for get value

```
tableView.addEventListener('click',function(e){
// own your requirement
 Ti.API.log(e);

});
```

I think this is easy to use and good looking.
If, you want to show and hide. then you can use animation or window.modal property.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({});
win.add(tableview);
win.open({modal:true});
```